# How to apply linear gradients for the entire webpage when having multiple sections with 100vh?

Tags: css, background, viewport, linear-gradients

I'd like to have a linear gradient for my entire website using HTML/CSS - starting from one color (say red) at the beginning to another (say blue) at the end. When users request the page, they first see a blue background turning gradually to a red background as they scroll down. The website should be separated by sections, each of them filling the entire screen.

The problem is that when I separate the website with sections using 100vh, the linear gradient repeats itself for each section - instead of linearly changing over the sections.

Here is the code I have used so far:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #202020));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="">first section</div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="">second section</div>
</section>
```

Any ideas on how to extend the linear gradient background over the sections? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: remove this: `background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: all what you need is one line `body {background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);}`

Comment: body{ background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%) no-repeat; }

Comment: @TaterOfTots we don't really need the no-repeat since there is no background-size defined and no border

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif, this is exacty what I was looking for. Works like a charm! I will look more into your comments to understand what's going on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't exactly what you are after, but you might be able to achieve what you want by adjusting the gradient percentages. I have added different gradients to each section and set the `background-attachment` to `static`.

If you are after a different effect you may have to use Javascipt/jQuery.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body > section:nth-child(1) {
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #202020));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #202020 100%);
}
body > section:nth-child(2) {
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #39a7cc 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #39a7cc 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #39a7cc 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #202020), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #39a7cc 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #39a7cc 30%, #ffffff 100%);
}
section {
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: static;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="">first section</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="">second section</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks @WizardCoder for taking the time to answer this question even though it was not exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks anyway!